# how to sort prime react table?

Tags: javascript, json, primereact

sorting in my table is not working.

[image]

LeftIcon - sort, RightIcon - filter.
https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-feather-phzm1j?file=/src/App.js - my project

I'm assuming due to the nesting in the data, how do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to nesting of data.  You have two choices...

1. Flatten your JSON to be more friendly to the built in sorting.
2. Use `sortFunction` on the column to write a custom sort on how that column should be sorted.